# Android app doesnt work on version 4.0 +

Tags: android

I have made an app that works on version 1.6 and above but once I updated my phone to 4.0.4 it gives me the following error, unfortunately, test has stopped and it wont run at all. Any reason as to why this might have happened? maybe I need to change something on the coding to make it work on the new version?
    package com.droidnova.android;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
  protected boolean _active = true;
  protected int _splashTime = 5000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.droidnova.android.splashscreen.MyApp"));
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the full logcat and any relevant code.

Comment: I have a splashcreen template that i downloaded here is the code: apparently when the thread is killed it stops the whole app completely, which it didnt on the older versions.

Comment: As Sam said, still need logcat data to see what your error is. But right off the bat, you're calling stop() which you really shouldn't do.

Comment: i finally solved the problem, it was the stop function that was making everything go crazy thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

a wild guess would be that you are calling finish() and startActivity() in another thread than the UI thread. use either an asynctask instead of the thread or use Activity.runOnUiThread(). and yes, the logcat would be helpful.